# How to access nested array in json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a ajax call and as a return i have json object. 
I can access information like 'status' or 'info' with

```
// handle a successful response
                        success : function(json) {
                            if (json.result == 'ok') {
                                console.log('sanity check - iccid:' + json.iccid);
                                console.log('sanity check - amount:' + json.amount);
                            } else if (json.result == 'error'){
                                console.log('sanity check - error: ' + json.info);
                            };
```

but in this json object i have another array:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 31,
        "model": "simcard.voucher",
        "fields": {
            "amount": 5,
            "voucher_no": "4762"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 32,
        "model": "simcard.voucher",
        "fields": {
            "amount": 5,
            "voucher_no": "4912"
        }
    }
]
```

First I would like to get vouchers quantity. I tried with `json.vouchers.length` but I got characters quantity.
Then I would like to iterate over vouchers. With:

```
var v = json.vouchers;
 for(var i in v)
  {
   console.info( v[i].pk);
   console.info( v[i].model);
   console.info( v[i].fields.amount);
   console.info( v[i].fields.voucher_no);
   }
```

I got error `TypeError: v[i].fields is undefined`

If I output whole json reponse to console I get:

```
Object { amount=10,  iccid="894422",  vouchers="[{"pk": 31, "model": "simcard.voucher", "fields": {"amount": 5, "voucher_no": "4762"}}, {"pk": 32, "model": "simcard.voucher", "fields": {"amount": 5, "voucher_no": "4912"}}]"  }
```

Hope you can guide me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like your vouchers field is actually a string. Try to check its type `console.info(typeof json.vouchers)`. If it is so, parse it manually by following `json.vouchers = JSON.parse(json.vouchers)`

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as JSON object.  You either have a `JSON` *string*, or you have converted it to an object.

Comment: thanks for tips. I just copied what I had in console. And it is 'String'. Checked with `typeof`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to parse your json to a js object.

```
var v = JSON.parse(json.vouchers)
```